# parte do meu código php é exibido no navegador, quando não abro com o localhost. Como solucionar?

Tags: php, html

[image: o erro]

```
if ($validacao) {
$pdo = Banco::conectar();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "INSERT INTO perguntas (p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($p1, $p2, $p3, $p4, $p5, $p6, $p7, $p8, $p9, $p10));
Banco::desconectar();
header("Location: index.php");
```

}

Comment: reveja seu código, veja onde fecham e abrem as tags de php, algo deve estar escapando

Comment: ja revisei varias vezes, mas não consigo identificar. Sou novo na linguagem

Comment: esse seu trecho de código está muito pequeno... seu erro pode estar em outro trecho ou arquivo

Comment: essa é a única parte do código que aparece no navegador. Creio que o resto esta certo

Comment: Pode revelar seu **código completo**? Assim posso ter uma ideia do que fazer para te ajudar (pois eu quase nem sei PHP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá.

Esse é o comportamento esperado. Um arquivo PHP é um arquivo de texto comum, e deve ser entendido assim pelo browser. O fato de parte de seu código ter sido interpretado quando acessado como arquivo mostra que algo não está certo. Se tudo estivesse correto, seu site deveria funcionar apenas através de `http://localhost/` ou `127.0.0.1` (já que, assim, o XAMPP interpreta o PHP e envia apenas HTML, CSS e JS para o browser) e exibir o código PHP inteiro ao acessar `file:///<...>`. Por exemplo:

[image: Veja um código de exemplo que é exibido por completo quando aberto no navegador via <code>file:///</code>]

Sendo assim, tente limpar seu cache e atualizar a página, ou acessar de outro navegador. O conteúdo exibido deve ser texto simples.

Se o problema persistir, envie seu código completo.

Comment: você tinha razão. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Isso é fácil identificar, podem ser duas coisas:

1. Você inseriu o seu código PHP fora do bloco PHP. Ele acaba sendo enviado como HTML e é mostrado na tela.
2. Você não tem o servidor PHP na sua máquina, ou não está ativado.
3. Você acessou o arquivo diretamente ao invés de "navegar" até ele.

No seu caso, é a terceira opção, porque lá na barra de endereços está escrito `"file:///C:/..."` Isso ocorre quando alguém tenta abrir o arquivo do código-fonte. Por padrão, ele exibe o HTML, CSS e JS normalmente, pois já são interpretados automaticamente pelo navegador, pois já possuem a configuração embutida, o que não é o caso do PHP, que precisa de um servidor instalado a parte no seu computador ou servidor (assim como o Java, C#, React etc).

Você deve ter dado dois cliques no arquivo, ou arrastou-o para dentro do navegador.

E como resolve?
Basta habilitar o seu servidor PHP e navegar pela URL até a sua página, usando o `"localhost"` ou `"127.0.0.1"`.